# Find elements between selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Below is my HTML content

```
<HR><HR><H3>Document_1</H3>
    <PRE>PART2_1</PRE>
    <PRE>PART2_2</PRE>
<HR><HR><H3>Document_2</H3>
    <PRE>PART3_1</PRE>
    <PRE>PART3_2</PRE>
    <PRE>PART3_3</PRE>
```

I want to wrap all the elements between `<HR><HR><H3>......<PRE></PRE>` into different DIVs. In other words I will have 2 `<DIV>`. I have tried various selectors but unable to get the right jquery.

Comment: The desired output for the example given here would help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var h3 = $('hr+hr+h3'), prev = $(h3).prevAll('hr'), div = $('<div>'), next = $(h3).nextAll('pre')
if ( prev.length && h3.length == 1 && next.length ) {
    $(h3).after(div).appendTo(div)
    $(prev).prependTo(div)
    $(next).appendTo(div)
}
```

You can probably use that as an example if I misunderstood.

Comment: Sorry for confusion! I wanted my output to be 
<div>
<HR><HR><H3>Document_1</H3>    <PRE>PART2_1</PRE>    <PRE>PART2_2</PRE>
</div>
<div>
  <HR><HR><H3>Document_2</H3>    <PRE>PART3_1</PRE>        <PRE>PART3_2</PRE>    <PRE>PART3_3</PRE>
<div>

Comment: Mine would work for one set, you'd need to probably use .each if there are multiple sets exactly like that. See if you can solve it :)

Comment: @meder - it's not as simple as you think to add `.each` here - `nextAll` will select all `<pre>` tags, even after other `h3`s. This could work if you'll go from last to first - by moving siblings into the div. either way, this is complex for jQuery...

Comment: Well yeah I guess you'd need some other function to handle the whole sibling business.. which brings me to my next question - why is the markup like this? What are all the possible combinations of this markup?